# chrome, source map not loading

Tags: google-chrome, source-maps

I am generating the bundled.js file using webpack for a typical angular project.  Now I deploy this on the web server.  The bundle.js file has the following at the end

```
//# sourceMappingURL=main.bundle.js.map
```

However Chrome does not seem to detect that there is a sourcemap available.  It does not even show the icon saying that a source map is available.  How do I fix this?  Plus should the path to the sourcemap be http://url/main.bundle.js.map?  How does chrome know where to load the sourcemap from?

Comment: **See Also**: [Sourcemaps are detected in chrome but original source is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39146381/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

For chrome, source-map was not loading/working for me too. I kept on seeing the bundle.js files. However, in other browsers it worked, that are chrome related like Brave. So I just went into my chrome browses dev-tools settings > preferences and then in the bottom right, I clicked the "Restore defaults and refresh" button and it worked fine after.

Comment: Not sure why it worked but it did, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

These are the runes you are looking for (chromeDevTools):

Map `webpack://./` to `/`

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit @jake?  What underlying problem does this solve?

Comment: This tells chrome that the files under webpack's virtual directory should be mapped to your project directory.