# Why are sourcemaps loading for users/developers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

This [question was answered with configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910585/chrome-source-map-not-loading) for webpack.  I am trying to get source maps working myself and wondering why chrome (and firefox) are not respecting the comment

```
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

I thought I should see a network request to the server in devtools for the map file, right?  Why is that not happening and how do we modify the main.js file created by webpack OR the *.js file created by our other tools **such that it works without configuring chrome developer tools** like was done before.  I figure since both firefox and chrome are not working, there must be some new standard I am missing?  (but not sure since webpack does not seem to do it properly?)

Firefox says it should be just do the above here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map