# Webpack & Gatsby - can't get sourcemaps to work

Tags: webpack, source-maps, gatsby

### Description

I'm trying to get SCSS SourceMaps working in our project but nothing seems to be working to get them enabled, I'm not sure what i'm missing here. To be honest i'm very new to webpack and have only used Gulp before, So I really have no Idea where i'm meant to enable them. Would anyone be able to take a look at my gatsby-node.js and tell me where i'm going wrong?

#### Environment

- Gatsby version (`npm list gatsby`): 1.9.183
- Node.js version: 8.9.4
- Operating System: Windows 10

#### File contents (if changed):

`gatsby-node.js`:

````
```
const _ = require(`lodash`);
const Promise = require(`bluebird`);
const path = require(`path`);
const slash = require(`slash`);
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const { cssModulesConfig } = require(`gatsby-1-config-css-modules`)

exports.createLayouts = ({graphql, boundActionCreators}) => {
    const {createLayout} = boundActionCreators;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        graphql(`
            {
              directusGlobal {
                  directusId
                  description
                  keywords
                  og_title
                  og_description
                  og_url
                  og_type
                  robots
                  geo_placename
                  geo_position
                  geo_region
                  icbm
                  og_image
                  og_site_name
                  fb_app_id
              }
            }
        `).then(result => {
            if (result.errors) {
                console.log(result.errors);
                reject(result.errors);
            }


            if (result.data !== undefined) {
                createLayout({
                    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/layouts/main-layout.js`),
                    context: result.data.directusGlobal,
                })
            }
            resolve();
        })
    })
}

// Implement the Gatsby API "onCreatePage". This is
// called AFTER every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, boundActionCreators }) => {
    const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        page.layout = "main-layout";

        // Update the page.
        createPage(page);
        resolve();
    });
};

exports.createPages = ({graphql, boundActionCreators}) => {
    const {createPage} = boundActionCreators;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        graphql(`
            {
                allDirectusPost {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            id
                            slug
                            status
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `).then(result => {
            if (result.errors) {
                console.log(result.errors);
                reject(result.errors);
            }
            const pageTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/blog/Post.js');
            if (result.data !== undefined) {
                _.each(result.data.allDirectusPost.edges, edge => {
                    if (edge.node.slug !== '') {
                        createPage({
                            path: `/blog/${edge.node.slug}`,
                            component: slash(pageTemplate),
                            layout: 'main-layout',
                            context: {
                                id: edge.node.id,
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }).then(() => {
            graphql(`
                {
                    allDirectusPackage(filter: {type: {eq: "Limited Company"}}) {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                directusId
                                name
                                price
                                description
                                slug,
                                products {
                                    data {
                                        id
                                        name
                                        description
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            `).then(result => {
                if (result.errors) {
                    console.log(result.errors);
                    reject(result.errors);
                }
                const pageTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/package/Package.js');
                if (result.data !== undefined) {
                    _.each(result.data.allDirectusPackage.edges, edge => {
                        if (edge.node.slug !== '') {
                            createPage({
                                path: `/${edge.node.slug}`,
                                component: slash(pageTemplate),
                                layout: 'main-layout',
                                context: {
                                    name: edge.node.name,
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }).then(() => {
            graphql(`
                {
                    allDirectusService(filter: {type:{regex: "/^(additional-service|address-service)$/"}}) {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                directusId
                                name
                                subheading
                                renewal_text
                                price
                                slug
                                faqs {
                                    data {
                                        question
                                        answer
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            `).then(result => {
                if (result.errors) {
                    console.log(result.errors);
                    reject(result.errors);
                }
                const pageTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/services/Service.js');
                if (result.data !== undefined) {
                    _.each(result.data.allDirectusService.edges, edge => {
                        if (edge.node.slug !== '') {
                            createPage({
                                path: `/services/${edge.node.slug}`,
                                layout: 'main-layout',
                                component: slash(pageTemplate),
                                context: {
                                    name: edge.node.name,
                                    id: edge.node.id
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
                resolve();
            })
        })
    })
}



exports.modifyWebpackConfig = function (_ref, options) {

    var config = _ref.config,
        stage = _ref.stage;

    var cssFiles = /\.css$/;
    var sassFiles = /\.s[ac]ss$/;
    var sassModulesFiles = /_\.s[ac]ss$/;
    var sassLoader = `sass?${JSON.stringify(options)}!import-glob`;

    config.merge({
        resolve: {
            root: path.resolve('./src'),
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
        },
        module: {
            noParse: /node_modules\/reactstrap-tether\/dist\/js\/tether.js/,
        },
        // { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(scssLoader) }, // SASS & CSS FILES
        // {test: /\.css/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(cssLoader)},
    });

    config.loader(`sass`, {
        test: sassFiles,
        exclude: sassModulesFiles,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([`css?minimize`, sassLoader],{            options: {
            sourceMap: true
        }}),
    });

    config.loader(`sassModules`, {
        test: sassModulesFiles,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(`style`, [
            cssModulesConfig(stage),
            sassLoader,
        ],
        { options: { sourceMap: true }}),
    });

    config.removeLoader('css');
    config.loader('css', function(cfg) {
        cfg.test = /\.css$/;
        cfg.loader = ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css?minimize',{
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
        }});
        return cfg
    })
    config.plugin('extract-css',
        ExtractTextPlugin,
        ["styles.css", { allChunks: true }]);

    return config
};

exports.modifyBabelrc = ({ babelrc }) => ({
    ...babelrc,
    plugins: babelrc.plugins.concat(['transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-regenerator']),
})
```
````

Comment: **See Also**: [Sourcemaps are detected in chrome but original source is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39146381/1366033)